# Question mark before dot in javascript / react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, optional-chaining

I know what a [ternary operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) is in React.

When I'm developing a React Native app I encounter this kind of syntax that is covered by my ESLint as an unexpected token:

`ESLint: Parsing error: Unexpected token .`

It goes like this:

`const routeName = route.state?.routes[route.state.index]?.name ?? INITIAL_ROUTE_NAME;`

What does that mean? It uses [null coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator) in the end, however, I can't understand what the question mark does before a dot.

I know it is the correct syntax because it is a template from [expo](https://expo.io/dashboard/robertwt7) and they're very popular in the React Native development community.

Can anyone help me explain?

Comment: that's why Stack Overflow is so great - you can be sure that others have tried to look for it the same way :)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

That's optional chaining: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The **optional chaining** operator (`?.`) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.
>
> The `?.` operator is like the `.` chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`. When used with function calls, it returns `undefined` if the given function does not exist.
>
> This results in shorter and simpler expressions when accessing chained properties when the possibility exists that a reference may be missing. It can also be helpful while exploring the content of an object when there's no known guarantee as to which properties are required.