# What is does the question mark followed by fullstop in javascript mean?

Tags: javascript

I have no idea what `?.` means. Example:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.post) {
      // Post updated, do something with `route.params.post`
      // For example, send the post to the server
    }
  }, [route.params?.post]);
```

It's hard to google the answer. I just see articles on the conditional (ternary) operator.

Comment: It's [Optional_chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: @jonrsharpe that duplicate link links to another closed question, not the original :)

Comment: _“It's hard to google the answer.”_ - not if you do it right. “javascript question mark followed by dot” led to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15260732/does-typescript-support-the-operator-and-whats-it-called in no time.

Comment: And your question title typed into Google _verbatim_, would’ve also relatively easy found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847231/question-mark-before-dot-in-javscript-react