# Access a property within the same object without declaring it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an `array of objects` that I need to loop through to create a new object with different properties. The problem is that when creating the new object I need to access a property before it is declared.

This is my source object:

```
let data = [
  {
    "name": "one",
    "total": 12,
    "fec": "001"
  },
  {
    "name": "one",
    "total": 1,
    "fec": "002"
  },
  {
    "name": "two",
    "total": 5,
    "fec": "001"
  }  
]
```

This is what I do:

```
let result;
data.forEach((item) => {
  result = {
    name: item.name,
    result: data.find((item) => item.fec === '001') ?.total,
    dto: this.result + 5
  }
})
```

My problem: how can I access the `result` property from the `dto` property inside the `forEach()`

Comment: What's the point of the `forEach` loop? At the end, `result` will just contain the object from the last element of `data`.

Comment: The language does not allow references to "under-construction" objects in the middle of the object initializer.

Comment: you can save the `data.find((item) => item.fec === '001') ?.total` to a variable and access it inside the object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the value in a variable before putting it in the result object.

Your code also isn't returning all the results, it keeps overwriting the `result` variable with a different object. Use `map()` to return all of them as an array.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "name": "one",
    "total": 12,
    "fec": "001"
  },
  {
    "name": "one",
    "total": 1,
    "fec": "002"
  },
  {
    "name": "two",
    "total": 5,
    "fec": "001"
  }  
];

let result = data.map((item) => {
  let r = data.find((item) => item.fec === '001')?.total;
  return {
    name: item.name,
    result: r,
    dto: r + 5
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does that ```?.total```, questionmark and dot means here?

Comment: [optional chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847231/question-mark-before-dot-in-javscript-react)

Comment: @Barmar
Sorry but when I list elements in data, I cannot see a difference before and after your code.
So what is result and how to access it?
Did you add a property in data or elsewhere???
Comments more than appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: It's not changing the original `data`, it's creating a new object and assigning that to `result`.

Comment: @Barmar I only get a function when I try to access it and don't find any key nor index

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to get all the results.